# Jekyll and Liquid - Filter redundant entries in list

Tags: arrays, redundancy

i would like to generate a list of posts ordered by a variable in the posts without redundant entries.

yaml:

```
---
time: 15 minutes
---
```

liquid:

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
    {% capture currentTime %}{{ post.time }}{% endcapture %}
    {% if currentTime %}
        <div class="sublist-italic">{{ currentTime }}</div>
    {% endif %}
    {% if post.category == 'recipe' %}  
        <li><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>            
    {% endif %}          
{% endfor %}
```

The result:

[image]

How can i put all values of a post variable in an array, filter the duplicates and assign the corresponding post titles?

Thanks for your help!